# ClosedXML Add WorkSheet with Conditional Formatting

Tags: c#, openxml, conditional-formatting, closedxml, office-2016

I am using ClosedXML to add new worksheet to existing Excel document.
It works fine for normal Excel document.

But if a excel document sheet contains conditional formatting on some cell then it throws error

```
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLCFConverters.Convert(IXLConditionalFormat conditionalFormat, Int32 priority, SaveContext context)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.GenerateWorksheetPartContent(WorksheetPart worksheetPart, XLWorksheet xlWorksheet, SaveContext context)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.CreateParts(SpreadsheetDocument document)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.CreatePackage(String filePath, SpreadsheetDocumentType spreadsheetDocumentType)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.SaveAs(String file)
```

Below is the sample code

```
using (var excelDoc = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook(strFilePath))
{
    excelDoc.Worksheets.Add("New Result Sheet");                    
    excelDoc.SaveAs(strFilePathSave);
}
```

Please help how to fix this issue.

Answer (score -2):

[XlsIO](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/XlsIO) is a .NET library that reads and writes Excel 2003/2007/2010/2013/2016 files. Using XlsIO, you can add/modify a worksheet with conditional formatting very easily without issues. The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license program](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Step 1: Create a console application

Step 2: Add reference to    Syncfusion.XlsIO.Base and Syncfusion.Compression.Base, you can add   these reference to your project using NuGet also.

Step 3: Copy &    paste the following code snippet.

The following code snippet illustrates how to add a worksheet with conditional formatting using XlsIO

```
using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
{
    //Instantiate the excel application object.
    IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;

    application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2013;

    //Open the workbook
    IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open("Input.xlsx");

    (workbook.Worksheets as WorksheetsCollection).Add("NewSheet");

    IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];

    IConditionalFormats condition = worksheet.Range["A1"].ConditionalFormats;

    IConditionalFormat condition1 = condition.AddCondition();

    condition1.FormatType = ExcelCFType.CellValue;

    condition1.Operator = ExcelComparisonOperator.Between;

    condition1.FirstFormula = "10";

    condition1.SecondFormula = "20";

    condition1.BackColor = ExcelKnownColors.Red; 

    worksheet.Range["A1"].Number = 13;

    //Save the workbook
    workbook.SaveAs("AddedWorkbook.xlsx");
}
```

Kindly refer the sample to achieve this scenario and the sample can be downloaded from following location.

[Download Demo](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Adding_Worksheet1384196038.zip)

For further information about XlsIO, please refer our [help documentation](http://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/xlsio/overview)

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Comment: I am not going to use this. If you know the fix/work around for this in ClosedXML then it will be of great help.